# How to get the ScanResult from WifiStateMachine?

Tags: java, android

How do I get the Scan result of Wifi from the `wifiStateMachine`?
and how do I avoid empty list?

I have tried to use `wifiManager.getScanResult();` to obtain the list, and it return empty

Comment: I have try to use wifiManager.getScanResult(); to obtain the list, and it return empty

Comment: Have a look at:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan

it is well explained, also check that you have the permissions for your app to access/change the wifi settings.